# how can get period session id for audio recorder in android 2.3.3

Tags: android

I want to get sessionID for the Audio recoder.API level 16 to get session ID fine..But when came to API level 10 no option to get session ID..How can get SessionID for android Audio Recorder???

**OR**

Any other way to get the Audio Recorder session iD??

Anyone please help me

Answer (score 0):

You can use getAudioSessionId Method
(This method can be called in any state and calling it does not change the object state)

Comment: But this method available API level 16..I want to do API level 10

Comment: New audio session ID that lets an application associate a set of audio effects with an instance of AudioTrack or MediaPlayer. 


New AudioTrack class constructor that lets you create an AudioTrack with a specific session ID. New attachAuxEffect(), getAudioSessionId(), and setAuxEffectSendLevel() methods. Get More Stuff here: [Android Recipe](http://androidrecipe.com)